# uninitialized constant error with SitePrism page

Tags: ruby, rspec, site-prism

I've added this to my spec_helper:

```
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'site_prism'
```

And my page is this:

```
class AboutPage < SitePrism::Page
end
```

My rspec is this:

```
require_relative 'spec_helper'

describe 'About Page' do

  it "test" do
    about = AboutPage.new
  end

end
```

The error I keep getting is:

Failures:

1) About Page test
     Failure/Error: about = AboutPage.new
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant AboutPage
     # ./about_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I needed to add to my spec_helper.rb:

```
require_relative about_page.rb
```

All pages you are using in your spec files have to be required before the can be used.

Comment: where is that 'spec_helper.rb'? I search for it on my project and saw a few references under Capybara, but I don't think I should be changing a gem just to add my pages, should I?

Even like that, I'm just starting on a new project and I cannot see them adding the SitePrism pages added anywhere, but they are able to create objects.Although I'm having the problem where I create a new page and I get this error (I'm asking that question here as I'm not sure why one works and the other doesn't). If you guys can think what I could try, please let me know...

Answer (score 0):

If AboutPage is not in the root path of `controller`, you must call it with a namespace like:

```
about = SomeNameSpace::AboutPage.new
```

Comment: what would be the value of 'SomeNameSpace'?, ie, where could I find that namespace on my project, not quite sure what it refers to...

Answer (score 0):

If all of your site prism objects are in `spec/page_objects`, using rspec, you could add this line to `rails_helper.rb`

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/page_objects/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
```

This will automatically require `about_page.rb` and any other page objects, including subfolders.